# vector push_back add new items

Tags: c++

I need add items to a vector who are created as `std::vector<char*> Lista;`

then i do:

```
char txt[10];
    for (int x = 0; x <= 5; x++)
    {
        
        sprintf(txt, "num%d", x);
        printf("Add %s\n", txt);

        Lista.push_back(txt);
    }
```

but if i loop Lista items it show show:

```
for (int x = 0; x <= Lista.size() - 1; x++)
    {
        printf("Items > [%d] %s\n", x, Lista[x]);
    }
```

Items > [0] num5

Items > [1] num5

Items > [2] num5

Items > [3] num5

Items > [4] num5

Items > [5] num5

what i'm doing wrong? i need use char* not string.

Comment: Each time you `push_back` a pointer to the same exact `char []`, so why do you expect see something different, for every value in the vector? It's the same pointer, each time, so it makes sense that you see the same value, right?

Comment: printf show right value Add num0
Add num1
Add num2
Add num3
Add num4
Add num5 but at vector is always last value.

Comment: Yes because youre calling printf as you go but you add a pointer to the same memory every time which means whatever you write last in it wins. (So when after the insert loop you print all the content you get the same thing 5 times)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're pushing five pointers to the same array into your vector, so when you print the contents of the array pointed to by each pointer they're all the same.

You only have a single array: `txt`.  Each time through your loop, you write new contents into that array and push a pointer to it into `Lista`.  So the first time through your loop you have this:

```
txt
┌─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬──────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┐
│     │     │     │     │      │     │     │     │     │     │
│ 'n' │ 'u' │ 'm' │ '0' │ '\0' │  ?  │  ?  │  ?  │  ?  │  ?  │
│     │     │     │     │      │     │     │     │     │     │
└─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴──────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┘
▲
│
└───┐
    │
┌───┼───┐
│   │   │
│   │   │
│       │
└───────┘
Lista
```

Then the second time through you modify `txt` and add another pointer to it to `Lista`, so you have this:

```
txt
┌─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬──────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┐
│     │     │     │     │      │     │     │     │     │     │
│ 'n' │ 'u' │ 'm' │ '1' │ '\0' │  ?  │  ?  │  ?  │  ?  │  ?  │
│     │     │     │     │      │     │     │     │     │     │
└─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴──────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┘
▲ ▲
│ └─────────┐
└───┐       │
    │       │
┌───┼───┬───┼───┐
│   │   │   │   │
│   │   │   │   │
│       │       │
└───────┴───────┘
Lista
```

And so on.  Every element of `Lista` contains a pointer to the same array, which you modify in each iteration of your loop.  When you go back and print the contents of the array pointed to by each element of `Lista`, they all point to the same array, so the same thing gets printed for each.

If you want to store different text in each element of `Lista`, you will need to create a separate string for each.  The easiest way to do that would be to change the type of `Lista` to `std::vector<std::string>` and let the `std::string` class handle allocating space for each string:

```
for (int x = 0; x <= 5; ++x) {
    std::string text = std::format(num{}, x);  // Use std::ostringstream or sprintf if your compiler doesn't support std::format
    Lista.push_back(text);
}
```

Then you can use `std::string`'s `data` member function to get a pointer to the string's underlying `char*` if you need to pass it to some interface that doesn't support `std::string`.  Keep in mind that the lifetime of the arrays pointed to by those pointers are tied to the lifetime of the `std::string` object, so be careful not to use them after the `std::string` (or the `std::vector` that contains it) goes out of scope.

If you absolutely do not want to use `std::string` to manage the lifetime of your arrays, you can allocate them yourself with `new[]`, just remember that you must then remember to `delete[]` them when you're done with them to avoid leaking memory:

```
for (int x = 0; x <= 5; ++x) {
    char* txt = new char[5];
    sprintf(txt, "num%d", x);
    Lista.push_back(txt);
}

// ... stuff

for (char* txt : Lista) {
    delete[] txt;
}
```

There are very few legitimate reasons to do this though.  In 99.9% of cases you should use `std::string` or some sort of smart pointer to manage your memory.

---

Note: Your program also exhibits undefined behavior because you access your array out of bounds with `Lista[x+1] = txt`; you should get rid of that line.

Comment: when i try use std::format i receive error C2039: 'format' : no es un miembro de 'std'. i use vs 2010. string is unicode?

Comment: `std::format` was added in C++20, so only very recent compilers will support it.  Like I said in the comment, if your compiler doesn't support `std::format` (VS 2010 doesn't; it's quite old) use `std::ostringstream` or `sprintf` or something.